# ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding

I am new to rails, I am using rails 3.2.3 in windows7. I have a project in rails when i run bundle install it was successful. And the rails server also working good. When i give localhost:3000 it throws an error like this,

```
 ERROR ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/win32console-1.3.2-x86-mingw32/lib/Win32/Console/ANSI.rb:163:in `sub!'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/win32console-1.3.2-x86-mingw32/lib/Win32/Console/ANSI.rb:163:in `_PrintString'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/win32console-1.3.2-x86-mingw32/lib/Win32/Console/ANSI.rb:146:in `block in write'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/win32console-1.3.2-x86-mingw32/lib/Win32/Console/ANSI.rb:146:in `each'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/win32console-1.3.2-x86-mingw32/lib/Win32/Console/ANSI.rb:146:in `write'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:29:in `print'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:29:in `tail!'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:18:in `call'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

i am unable to figure out where the exact problem. I searched in google but no relevent solution. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

May you have latin chars (á,é,í,ó,ú,ñ) in view messages, sometimes you can generate invalid chars when you copy the code between different Operating Systems.

Try to review view files looking for special chars and try to remove them in order to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because of the spaces before each command in the `fastfile`. The commands under each lane must be indented inwards by a space.

```
  lane :beta do
   gradle(task: 'assemble')  #correct (one space)

    gradle(task: 'assemble') #incorrect (many spaces)
  end
```

Answer (score -7):

Try using a more *modern* rack server like [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/)

**Gemfile:**

```
gem 'thin'
```

**Console, run:**

```
$ bundle
$ rails s
```